# Question about synchronized execution of suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a callback function that is called very frequently, and each time it calls back it generates a different parameter. Using this parameter, I need to call a suspend function. But note: I have to make sure that I call this function strictly according to the order in which the arguments are generated.

So it's not appropriate to launch a concatenation in the callback and then execute the suspend function, after all, the order of launching doesn't always match the order of execution.

Channel.trySend() is a non-suspend function, and it seems like a solution idea, but is there another way?

I came up with `runBlocking {}` , which generally works. But in some cases, such as when the callback is in the main thread and my suspend function also needs to be called in main, it will deadlock.

Is it possible to avoid using runBlocking and call my suspend function synchronously?

Comment: What’s wrong with Channel.trySend? The other option would be to use `callbackFlow` to set up your listener and then collecting the flow, but this is just a different way of using the Channel. Definitely do not use runBlocking if you don’t like your app crashing with ANRs and deadlocks!

Comment: Because of flow control. I want to block the callback when the Channel is full. If I use the result of trySend and runs into a failed result, I need to use a complex method for the delay. Thank you very much. I'll try it.

Comment: Please throw in some code examples/snippets. I'm struggling to visualise what the problem is.

Comment: A [mre] would be best.

Comment: IMO needs code samples